# How to resolve a makefile override issue when its the same target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

```
targets: abc xyz

define TAR

display:
        @echo "XXXXXXXXXX"    


$(1) : display xxx-$(1)


xxx-$(1):
         *do target specific action -- $(1) is input to a script*

endef

$(foreach x,$(targets),$(eval $(call TAR,$(x))))
```

This is the code i have which is causing an issue with the override when i added xyz as one of the targets. Is this approach wrong ?

the command i triggered on command line >> make abc

Comment: Please format your code as code. And what do you mean by "issue with the override"?

Comment: Please show the command you typed and the result you got (cut and pasted with formatting) and explain what about the result is not what you wanted.

Comment: At first glance, you are creating the `display` target multiple times, that is, you are creating multiple recipes for the same target, which is understandably illegal.

Comment: The command i triggered is added now and @Vroomfondel, thank you for the hint. i moved the display out of the block , it ok now.

Comment: IMO this model is not good.  It's never a great idea in make to try to use a peer prerequisite as a "subroutine" to be run "first".  That's because if you ever wanted to enable parallel builds, it will not work the way you want: in your makefile above if you enable parallel builds the `display` target and the `xxx-$(1)` target will be run in parallel.  Also by having a prerequisite like `display` which doesn't actually build any targets, it means that your `$(1)` targets are always out of date and will always build.  Maybe that's OK, depending on what they actually do.

Comment: I plan to add .NOTPARALLEL in the Makefile so that the targets never run in parallel.Yes the target will always run as i want to display some information and then go ahead and always build. In my usecase it is ok to always run

Comment: You are using a variable `targets` that is not defined in the makefile code presented.  You have a *target* named "targets" -- did you mean that to be a variable?